# Ember.js - add a maxBinding to Ember.TextField

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I was wondering what is the easiest way to acheive the following:

```
{{view Ember.TextField type="number" maxBinding="quantity" valueBinding="firstName"}}
```

The above doesn't work - all I need to do is bind a value to the `max` attribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The max attribute is not bound by default. See [text_field.js](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/controls/text_field.js#L56)

The easiest way would be to create your own textfield by extending the existing one like this:

```
App.MyTextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
    attributeBindings: ['max']
});
```

Then you should be able to do this:

```
{{view App.MyTextField type="number" maxBinding="quantity" valueBinding="firstName"}}
```

Comment: Worked perfect, thanks. I'll accept this answer as soon as it lets me